# sql counting query returns incorrect numbers

Tags: sql, count, oracle11g

I wrote a sql query to get the frequencies of words.  I create a new column, separate words by #'s and then count their occurrences.  However, the query is taking hours and hours to run on the full dataset (about 14,000 rows).  So I ran it on just a few ID's and I'm getting counts of some words as 16,000+ when it should only be ~20 or so.

Here is my query:

```
WITH mydata as 
( 
--query for test column
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(TEST), ' ', '#') test 
    FROM (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (replace(description,'-','.'), '[' ||  
    REGEXP_REPLACE (replace(description,'-','.') || '!', '[^[:punct:]]')  || ']') test 
    FROM my_table)
), 
splitted_words as 
( 
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(TEST,'[^#]+', 1, level) AS word 
FROM mydata 
CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(regexp_replace(TEST,'[^#]')) + 1 
AND PRIOR TEST = TEST 
AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL 
) 
SELECT word, 
COUNT(1) 
FROM splitted_words
GROUP BY word;
```

my column I'm looping over looks something like this:

```
TEST
 ---------------------------------------------
 SPOKE#WITH#MR#SMITHS#ASSISTANT
 EMAILED#FOR#VISIT
 SCHEDULING#OFFICE#LM#FOR#VISIT
 LM#FOR#VISIT
 LM#FOR#VISIT
 PHONE#CALL
 ---------------------------------------------
```

but my results are looking something like this:

```
word | count
-----|------
LM   |  20
Visit|  24
Phone| 8161
With |  16
Email| 16080
```

when clearly, there is not 16,000 occurrences of the word "email"

any idea why I'm getting insanely high numbers for some words? )and therefore causing the query to take 12+ hours to run?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you check for `AND PRIOR TEST = TEST`.

In your example, this will find two rows, not only the one you are currently working with:

```
 LM#FOR#VISIT
 LM#FOR#VISIT
```

It would work if you had some id-column to use, or you could even check for `PRIOR ROWID = ROWID` instead.

Comment: oh, that makes sense! how would I get the row_id in there with my test column? so i can do the check for prior row_id?  I'm relatively new to sql and it took hours to get this query semi-right

Comment: `ROWID` is a column already provided by Oracle, so you can just use it as I described. If there is a primary key on your table, use it instead.